# htaccess allow from subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I have restrict rules in htaccess

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.111.222.222
```

How could I make something like this?

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from sub.domain.tld
```

My IP is changing frequently and I have domain name A DNS record for this IP as sub.domain.tld. This would save me much time when my IP changes because I don't need to change all htaccess files with the new one IP.

I tried it but unfrotunatelly it is not working. Any workaround for this? Many thanks.

Comment: You can very well do `allow from sub.domain.tld`

Comment: I tried it but it is not working for me. I am opening requested website from IP which is as IP in DNS records as sub.domain.tld. Doesn't work.

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rewrite rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(11\.22\.33\.44|66\.77\.88\.99)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: thank you Anubhava! I tried it. It looks like rewritecond compares text host and not my IP associated with sub.domain.tld.

Comment: Yes that's correct. If you want to compare IP also let me edit the code.